# Saved 9800 WLC file cuts off configuration

Tags: python, cisco-ios

I am having an issue where my script logs into a Cisco WLC 9800, sends the commands "show run" and then saves it to a file, but the file cuts off a big chunk of the config.  I verified with a debug that the whole configuration is pulled from the command, just can't figure out why it is not working.  I have no issue pulling a full "show run" from a Cisco 4500 switch.

Here is my script:

```
device = {
   'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
   'ip': 'IP',
   'username': 'username',
   'password': 'password',
    }
##opening IP file
ipfile = open("C:\XXXX\switch-ips.txt")
print("Script to take backup of devices, Please enter your credentials")
device['username'] = input("User name: ")
device['password'] = getpass.getpass()

##taking backup
for line in ipfile:
    try:
       device['ip'] = line.strip("\n")
       print("\n\nConnecting to Device ", line)
       net_connect = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
       net_connect.enable()
       time.sleep(1)
       print("Reading the hostname")
       hostname = (net_connect.send_command('show run | i host').split()[1])
       print(hostname)
       print("Reading the running config ")
       output = net_connect.send_command('show run')
       time.sleep(2)
       filename = r'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Script Results\\' + hostname + '-' + today + ".txt"
       saveconfig = open(filename, 'w+')
       print("Writing Configuration to file")
       saveconfig.write(output)
       saveconfig.close()
       time.sleep(2)
       net_connect.disconnect()
       print("Configuration saved to file", filename)
   except:
       print("Access to " + device['ip'] + " failed, backup did not taken")
       continue
ipfile.close()
```

Comment: By "cut off" do you mean that the file only contains the config of the last entry in the IP file?

Comment: No, the file creates individual files for each IP address that is passed in.  When it comes to the WLC and it runs the "show run" it will show the whole configuration in the debug that I ran, but when it goes to write it to a text file, it only shows about 1/3 of the configuration.

Comment: How did you do the debugging?

Comment: In my script I had the following:
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename= r'C:\\Users\\XXXX\Script Results\\ios-xe.log', 
    level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger('netmiko')

Comment: And what did you write to the logger?

Comment: It shows the ssh connection, the show commands I run:
    DEBUG:netmiko:[find_prompt()]: prompt is USMHRXW001#
    DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'show run\n'
    C9800#
    DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: 
    DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: show run
    Building configuration...
    DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: (show\ run) 
    C9800#show run
"I then see the entire config"
    C9800#
    DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: 
    DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: 
    DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'exit\n'
    DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread

Comment: I meant what code did you write to write the configuration to the logger. Did you write `logger.debug(output)` just before `saveconfig.write(output)`?

Comment: I actually don't even had the logger.debug(output) command in there.  Otherwise my logging configs are at top of my config and is then before the saveconfig.write(output)  

import time                                                              
import logging   
logging.basicConfig(filename= r'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Script Results\\ios-xe.log',    
level=logging.DEBUG)   
logger = logging.getLogger('netmiko')